# Auto mouse click on a Sepcific area of screen

Tags: vb.net

I want to Make a software in `VB.NET`, which reads all screen content and click on a specific place after a specific time interval.
 Any one please help me how to start it.

Comment: And what you have tried? anything : searching on google, found any article, tried any code or some code that doesn't work?  you can get result quickly than SO. Yeah Google is must faster than SO when you try to find something that you want. SO only suggest on ur programming related issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Private Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" Alias "SetCursorPos" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
```

To set the cursor position use `SetCursorPos(x,y)`. `x` and `y` being the screen coordinates. 
To click: `mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN Or MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)`

You can find more details about calling Windows APIs in Visual Basic  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/172wfck9.aspx).